# Display List Item name from array ID's c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, join

I want to simplify the following process:

```
var _cat = new Categories();
_cat.GetCategories();
```

retrieves:

```
ID   Name

1    Men
2    Women
3    Unisex
4    Access
5    Kids


string[] prodCat = p.ProductCategory.Split(','); // Contains value 2,3,5
```

and to output to my label:

```
    foreach (Category c in _cat)
    {
        foreach (string pr in prodCat)
        {
            if (pr.Length > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(pr) == c.Id)
            {
                lblSaveCat.Text += c.CatName + " <br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

I am thinking there may be a more efficient way to do this rather than the loops maybe via linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.Join`:

```
var prodCat = p.ProductCategory.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

lblSaveCat.Text = string.Join(" <br />", _cats.Where(x => prodCat.Contains(x.Id)).Select(c => c.CatName));
```

BTW, you need to use `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine` if you want line break after each value. `<br />` is not gonna work unless your label displays html.

Answer (score 0):

that works great, had to do a minor edit as I had an extra comma at the end of prodCat:

```
    var _cat = new Categories();
    _cat.GetCategories();

    p.ProductCategory = p.ProductCategory + "0";

    var prodCat = p.ProductCategory.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

    lblSaveCat.Text = string.Join("\r\n", _cat.Where(x => prodCat.Contains(x.Id)).Select(c => c.CatName));
```